# Broken/corrupted apt and dpkg after trying to do a release upgrade which failed, now system can't update. I'm on WSL, not native ubuntu

Tags: apt, dpkg, 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So after running `do-release-upgrade`, the process failed prompting me to abort or resurrect this window (I don't remember what exactly was shown as an error and I can't replicate it because it's not broken even further).

Now after trying to do `apt update` I get this:

```
$>sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Fetched 312 kB in 2s (155 kB/s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

So I tried to re-install apt-pkg using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt`, which gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dnsutils : Depends: bind9-dnsutils but it is not going to be installed
 e2fsprogs : PreDepends: libext2fs2 (= 1.45.3-4ubuntu2.1) but 1.45.5-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
             Recommends: e2fsprogs-l10n but it is not going to be installed
 fwupd : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.63.3) but 2.62.4-1~ubuntu19.10.2 is to be installed
 gir1.2-glib-2.0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.63.3) but 2.62.4-1~ubuntu19.10.2 is to be installed
 gir1.2-pango-1.0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is to be installed
 glib-networking : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.63.0) but 2.62.4-1~ubuntu19.10.2 is to be installed
 glib-networking-services : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.63.0) but 2.62.4-1~ubuntu19.10.2 is to be installed
 golang-race-detector-runtime : Depends: golang-1.13-race-detector-runtime but it is not going to be installed
 gparted : Depends: gparted-common (= 1.0.0-0.1build1) but it is not going to be installed
 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libasound2 : Depends: libasound2-data (>= 1.2.2-2.1) but 1.1.9-0ubuntu1.3 is to be installed
 libcairo-gobject-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libcairo-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libfile-fcntllock-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libglib-object-introspection-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
                                     Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~) but 1.62.0-1 is to be installed
 libglib-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.64.2-1~fakesync1) but 2.62.4-1~ubuntu19.10.2 is to be installed
 libhtml-parser-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libicu-dev : Depends: icu-devtools (>= 66.1-2ubuntu2) but 63.2-2ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
              Breaks: icu-devtools (< 66.1-1~) but 63.2-2ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
 libnet-dbus-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libpam-modules : PreDepends: libpam-modules-bin (= 1.3.1-5ubuntu1.19.10.1) but 1.3.1-5ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libpangocairo-1.0-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is to be installed
 libpangoft2-1.0-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is to be installed
 libpangoxft-1.0-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.42.4-7 is to be installed
 libpci3 : Depends: pci.ids (>= 0.0~2019.11.10-2) but it is not going to be installed
 libpython-dev : Depends: libpython2-dev (= 2.7.17-1) but 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libpython-stdlib : Depends: libpython2-stdlib (= 2.7.17-1) but 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libtext-charwidth-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.30.0-8) but 5.28.1-6build1 is to be installed
                          Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libtext-iconv-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.30.0-8) but 5.28.1-6build1 is to be installed
                      Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libxml-parser-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.4+dfsg1-7ubuntu3.1) but 2.9.10+dfsg-5 is to be installed
 ncurses-bin : PreDepends: libtinfo6 (< 6.2~) but 6.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.30.0-9build1) but 5.28.1-6build1 is to be installed
        Depends: perl-modules-5.30 (>= 5.30.0-9build1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libperl5.30 (= 5.30.0-9build1) but it is not going to be installed
 python-all : Depends: python2 (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4) but 2.7.17-1 is to be installed
 python-all-dev : Depends: python2 (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4) but 2.7.17-1 is to be installed
 python-dev : Depends: python2-dev (= 2.7.17-1) but 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
 python-gi : Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~) but 1.62.0-1 is to be installed
 python-minimal : Depends: python2-minimal (= 2.7.17-1) but 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
 python-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 18.1-5) but 20.0.2-5ubuntu1 is to be installed
 python2 : PreDepends: python2-minimal (= 2.7.17-1) but 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
           Depends: libpython2-stdlib (= 2.7.17-1) but 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
 python2-dev : Depends: python2 (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4) but 2.7.17-1 is to be installed
 python3 : Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.7.5-1) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 python3-apt : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-cffi-backend : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-crypto : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-dbus : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
               Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-distutils : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8.0-1~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-gdbm : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8.0-1~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-gi : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
              Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~) but 1.62.0-1 is to be installed
 python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-lib2to3 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8.0-1~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-markupsafe : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-netifaces : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-newt : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-pyrsistent : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-simplejson : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-systemd : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-twisted-bin : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-venv : Depends: python3 (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-yaml : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-zope.interface : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
 systemd : Depends: systemd-timesyncd but it is not going to be installed or
                    time-daemon
 vim : Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5) but 2:8.1.0875-5ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Which prompts me to try and run `apt --fix-broken install`, which gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dh-python enchant geoip-database golang-1.12-go golang-1.12-race-detector-runtime golang-1.12-src javascript-common
  libapt-pkg5.90 libbind9-161 libcodec2-0.8.1 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libdns-export1104 libdns1104
  libenchant1c2a libept1.5.90 libevent-2.1-6 libgeoip1 libgnat-8 libgspell-1-1 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libhogweed4 libicu63
  libiptc0 libirs161 libisc-export1100 libisc1100 libisccc161 libisccfg163 libisl21 libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc
  libjs-underscore liblwres161 libmysofa0 libnettle6 libperl5.28 libplymouth4 libprocps7 libpython-all-dev
  libpython2-dev libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3.7
  libpython3.7-dev libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib libx265-176 perl-modules-5.28 python-all python-all-dev
  python-asn1crypto python-cffi-backend python-configparser python-crypto python-cryptography python-dbus
  python-entrypoints python-enum34 python-gi python-ipaddress python-keyring python-pkg-resources python-setuptools
  python-six python-xdg python2 python2-dev python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal
  python3-asn1crypto python3-nacl python3-pymacaroons python3-xdg python3.7 python3.7-dev python3.7-minimal
  python3.7-venv
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  alsa-topology-conf bind9-dnsutils e2fsprogs golang-1.13-race-detector-runtime gparted-common icu-devtools
  libasound2-data libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib2.0-0 liblocale-gettext-perl libpam-modules libpango-1.0-0 libperl5.30
  libpython3-dev libxml2-dev ncurses-bin pci.ids perl-base perl-modules-5.30 python2 python3 python3-minimal
  systemd-timesyncd vim-runtime
Suggested packages:
  gpart fuse2fs e2fsck-static alsa-utils python2-doc python-tk python3-doc python3-tk
Recommended packages:
  e2fsprogs-l10n
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libpython-dev libpython-stdlib nodejs python python-dev python-keyrings.alt python-minimal python-pip
  python-secretstorage python-wheel
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  alsa-topology-conf bind9-dnsutils golang-1.13-race-detector-runtime gparted-common libperl5.30 pci.ids
  perl-modules-5.30 systemd-timesyncd
The following packages will be upgraded:
  e2fsprogs icu-devtools libasound2-data libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib2.0-0 liblocale-gettext-perl libpam-modules
  libpango-1.0-0 libpython3-dev libxml2-dev ncurses-bin perl-base python2 python3 python3-minimal vim-runtime
16 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 10 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
835 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 18.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 34.1 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
                                                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                   wever:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libselinux1:amd64 depends on libpcre2-8-0 (>= 10.22); however:
  Package libpcre2-8-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libselinux1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libzstd1:amd64:
 libzstd1:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libzstd1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zlib1g:amd64:
 zlib1g:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zlib1g:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libacl1:amd64:
 libacl1:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After searching around I already tried these solutions:

1. `dpkg --configure -a` gives:

   ```
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnet-ssleay-perl:
    libnet-ssleay-perl depends on perlapi-5.30.0; however:
     Package perlapi-5.30.0 is not installed.

   dpkg: error processing package libnet-ssleay-perl (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distutils:
    python3-distutils depends on python3 (>= 3.8.0-1~); however:
     Version of python3 on system is 3.7.5-1.

   dpkg: error processing package python3-distutils (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dh-python:
    dh-python depends on python3-distutils | python3 (<< 3.6.5~rc1-1); however:
     Package python3-distutils is not configured yet.
     Version of python3 on system is 3.7.5-1.

   dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglib-object-introspection-perl:
    libglib-object-introspection-perl depends on perlapi-5.30.0; however:
     Package perlapi-5.30.0 is not installed.
    libglib-object-introspection-perl depends on libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~); however:
     Version of libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 on system is 1.62.0-1.

   dpkg: error processing package libglib-object-introspection-perl (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtext-iconv-perl:
    libtext-iconv-perl depends on perl-base (>= 5.30.0-8); however:
     Version of perl-base on system is 5.28.1-6build1.
    libtext-iconv-perl depends on perlapi-5.30.0; however:
     Package perlapi-5.30.0 is not installed.

   dpkg: error processing package libtext-iconv-perl (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of glib-networking-services:
    glib-networking-services depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.63.0); however:
     Version of libglib2.0-0:amd64 on system is 2.62.4-1~ubuntu19.10.2.

   dpkg: error processing package glib-networking-services (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtext-charwidth-perl:
    libtext-charwidth-perl depends on perl-base (>= 5.30.0-8); however:
     Version of perl-base on system is 5.28.1-6build1.
    libtext-charwidth-perl depends on perlapi-5.30.0; however:
     Package perlapi-5.30.0 is not installed.

   dpkg: error processing package libtext-charwidth-perl (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxml-parser-perl:
    libxml-parser-perl depends on perlapi-5.30.0; however:
     Package perlapi-5.30.0 is not installed.

   dpkg: error processing package libxml-parser-perl (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gi:
    python-gi depends on libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~); however:
     Version of libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 on system is 1.62.0-1.

   dpkg: error processing package python-gi (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of golang-race-detector-runtime:
    golang-race-detector-runtime depends on golang-1.13-race-detector-runtime; however:
     Package golang-1.13-race-detector-runtime is not installed.

   dpkg: error processing package golang-race-detector-runtime (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dbus:
    python3-dbus depends on python3 (>= 3.8~); however:
     Version of python3 on system is 3.7.5-1.

   dpkg: error processing package python3-dbus (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglib-perl:amd64:
    libglib-perl:amd64 depends on perlapi-5.30.0; however:
     Package perlapi-5.30.0 is not installed.





   --- a whole lot of these types of errors which I didn't include to save space ---






   dpkg: error processing package python3-jsonschema (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libipc-system-simple-perl:
    libipc-system-simple-perl depends on perl:any; however:
     Package perl is not configured yet.

   dpkg: error processing package libipc-system-simple-perl (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: too many errors, stopping
   Errors were encountered while processing:
    libnet-ssleay-perl
    python3-distutils
    dh-python
    libglib-object-introspection-perl
    libtext-iconv-perl
    glib-networking-services
    libtext-charwidth-perl
    libxml-parser-perl
    python-gi
    golang-race-detector-runtime
    python3-dbus
    libglib-perl:amd64
    vim
    python3-cairo:amd64
    python2-dev
    python3-setuptools
    libpangoxft-1.0-0:amd64
    libfile-fcntllock-perl
    python3-gdbm:amd64
    python3-zope.interface
    python3-apt
    update-notifier-common
    gparted
    libxml-twig-perl
    python3-twisted-bin:amd64
    libnet-dbus-perl
    libglib2.0-bin
    python3-yaml
    systemd
    python-all
    dnsutils
    ubuntu-standard
    python3-newt:amd64
    python3-distupgrade
    landscape-common
    python3-markupsafe
    software-properties-common
    python3-apport
    netplan.io
    python3-simplejson
    unattended-upgrades
    perl
    gir1.2-pango-1.0:amd64
    python3-jinja2
    libxml2-dev:amd64
    python3-venv
    python3-secretstorage
    python3-software-properties
    python3-jsonschema
    libipc-system-simple-perl
   Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
   ```
2. `apt install -f`  gives:

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   Correcting dependencies... Done
   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
     dh-python enchant geoip-database golang-1.12-go golang-1.12-race-detector-runtime golang-1.12-src javascript-common
     libapt-pkg5.90 libbind9-161 libcodec2-0.8.1 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libdns-export1104 libdns1104
     libenchant1c2a libept1.5.90 libevent-2.1-6 libgeoip1 libgnat-8 libgspell-1-1 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libhogweed4 libicu63
     libiptc0 libirs161 libisc-export1100 libisc1100 libisccc161 libisccfg163 libisl21 libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc
     libjs-underscore liblwres161 libmysofa0 libnettle6 libperl5.28 libplymouth4 libprocps7 libpython-all-dev
     libpython2-dev libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3.7
     libpython3.7-dev libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib libx265-176 perl-modules-5.28 python-all python-all-dev
     python-asn1crypto python-cffi-backend python-configparser python-crypto python-cryptography python-dbus
     python-entrypoints python-enum34 python-gi python-ipaddress python-keyring python-pkg-resources python-setuptools
                                                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                      wever:
     Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.
    libselinux1:amd64 depends on libpcre2-8-0 (>= 10.22); however:
     Package libpcre2-8-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

   dpkg: error processing package libselinux1:amd64 (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libzstd1:amd64:
    libzstd1:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
     Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

   dpkg: error processing package libzstd1:amd64 (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zlib1g:amd64:
    zlib1g:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
     Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

   dpkg: error processing package zlib1g:amd64 (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libacl1:amd64:
    libacl1:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
   ```

So right now I'm completely lost. I've already tried everything I could from what I could gather from the internet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

One thing to note, I'm on Windows under WSL. I was on Ubuntu 19.10 and ran `do-release-upgrade` to get to 20.04 LTS which failed. Afterwards, I saw that there was an update to Ubuntu from the Microsoft store to upgrade to 20.04. I downloaded that, ran `do-release-upgrade` again and it also failed. But if i run neofetch, It says that I'm actually running 20.04. I'm not sure if this is handy information but I thought i'd say it.

Comment: @Nmath I've used `do-release-upgrade` successfully in both WSL1 and WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, at this point you might consider uninstalling Ubuntu from your Windows PC and reinstalling 20.04. You can backup all your data and then restore it after you have reinstalled the OS.

This [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/261188/how-to-uninstall-or-reinstall-windows-10s-ubuntu-bash-shell/) might get you started.

Comment: I've got so many packages I use for development I wouldn't even know where to start to try and re-install them again...

Answer (score 0):

You've got very broken dependencies.

It is hard to tell you how to fix without knowing what went wrong.

If you are on WSL 1 you should stick to 18.04, up to 19.10, but hold off on upgrading to 20.04: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-and-wsl-1/15291

I would probably move my files off into Windows, on /mnt/c, and then uninstall. If you are on WSL 1, reinstall Ubuntu 18.04, if WSL 2, Ubuntu 20.04.

You can also sideload non-LTS releases: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL#Installing_Ubuntu_on_WSL_via_rootfs